# undefined method 'reverse' for 500

Tags: ruby

I am just learning ruby and this seems to be an easy mistake I am doing here right?

```
def palindromic(str)
    str.to_s
    if str.reverse == str
        puts "it is a palindromic number!"
    end
end

palindromic(500)
```

Instead I am getting an error

```
Project4.rb:5:in `palindromic': undefined method `reverse' for 500:Fixnum (NoMet
hodError)
        from Project4.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the line `str.to_s` to `str=str.to_s`. One example to show you why so is below :

```
num = 12
num.to_s # => "12"
num # => 12
num=num.to_s
num # => "12"
```

Basically [**`String#to_s`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_s) change the receiver instance to the instance of `String`.But if the receiver is already the `String` instance,in that case receiver itself will be returned.

```
ar = [1,2]
ar.object_id # => 77603090
ar.to_s.object_id # => 77602480
str = 'Hello'
str.object_id # => 77601890
str.to_s.object_id # => 77601890
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed the basics.